# Access ’aria-label‘ of Yelp review page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, yelp

I want to access the text ("5 star rating") in the `'aria label'`  with `BeautifulSoup`

```
<div class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc i-stars__373c0__1T6rz i-stars--regular-5__373c0__N5JxY border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU overflow--hidden__373c0__2y4YK" aria-label="5 star rating" role="img"><img class="lemon--img__373c0__3GQUb offscreen__373c0__1KofL" src="https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/public/stars_v2.yji-52d3d7a328db670d4402843cbddeed89.png" width="132" height="560" alt=""></div>
```

When I use `soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':' aria-label'})`, it returns an empty list.
Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

Here `aria-label` is not a class it's a attribute of div tag, So u need to access that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<div class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc i-stars__373c0__1T6rz i-stars--regular-5__373c0__N5JxY border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU overflow--hidden__373c0__2y4YK" aria-label="5 star rating" role="img"><img class="lemon--img__373c0__3GQUb offscreen__373c0__1KofL" src="https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/public/stars_v2.yji-52d3d7a328db670d4402843cbddeed89.png" width="132" height="560" alt=""></div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.div["aria-label"])
```